# Microcontroller to run x86 application

Tags: gaming, windows

I'm a big fan of Touhou games (PC-98 and Windows Era).

I wanted to make a custom console to be able to play them on tv (a plug and play like console).
For the PC-98 games, I was able to use a Raspberry PI with retroPie.

But now, I'm stuck for the windows games. I tried using Wine with a Linux environment to at least see if it would work. Which it didn't.

One of my friends recommended me to get a microcontroller with an x86 processor for that task. So I searched for a list of microcontrollers with that kind of specs but only found some that cost more than 70€.

Here is a list of the specs I at least need to run these games :

- DirectX 9.0
- 1-2 GB of RAM
- 512 MB of VRAM
- SD slot/16 GB of ROM
- DirectSound
- Less than 60 Euros

I don't know if anything with these specs exists for that price, but I hope that I can at least get some possible alternatives

Comment: Running x86 on ARM won't work with just Wine, you might have better luck with QEMU.

Comment: DirectX and DirectSound are Windows features. If you don't end up running Windows on the SBC you decide on, you will *have* to settle for Wine since that is the only other way to "emulate" (WINE is not an emulator) DirectX and DirectSound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Atomic Pi](https://dlidirect.com/products/atomic-pi) - it definitely satisfies all your hardware requirements. As for DirectX 9 and DirectSound those are software features which I am unable to comment on, although Wine might work in this case. The board should be able to run Windows too though.

If you want to check if the games work under Wine on x86 Linux try it on your PC first. You might also have a look at [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) which greatly simplifies the process on running games under Wine.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for. I can see that they are out of stock for now so I'm going to have to wait for the restocking. And I don't need the processing of windows (so windows 7 will be enough for that) I just need a way to launch x86 apps. And Wine didn't work well with Touhou games (framerate lag, controls delays...). But I'll try to get more documentation on that to see if it fit my project. Thank again for the help